# Motion not working with Pi Camera on Bullseye

Tags: camera, motion, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

motion as motion tracking software worked nice on buster but I have difficulties on bullseye. First it did not create motion.log and motion.pid files than it does not work with a raspi camera.

raspistill creates an image

v4l2-ctl -V shows

```
Width/Height      : 640/480
Pixel Format      : 'BA81' (8-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR)
Field             : None
Bytes per Line    : 640
Size Image        : 307200
Colorspace        : sRGB
Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
```

the camera configpart in motion.conf looks like

videodevice /dev/video0
v4l2_palette 2
input -1
norm 0

but the log shows

```
v4l2_norm_select: Device does not support specifying PAL/NTSC norm
v4l2_fps_set: Error setting fps. Return code -1
```

Comment: I suggest you go back to Buster, plenty of camera issues with Bullseye.

Comment: that would be sad if that would be the only solution :-(

Comment: @CoderMike Raspistill Works, so hopefully just a motion config issue

Comment: `Raspistill Works` - not in bullseye

Comment: it did work in bullseye with the pi camera on a zero w